# Windows 7 insists there is an extra language input

Tags: windows-7, windows, input-languages

This is a corporate image of Windows 7; it keeps inisiting that I have an extra input method while I don't.

See screens below:

Nothing else other than "US"

[image]

Yet, in the language menu bar "NL" adds itself, and it's the default input no mater how many times I switch. It's driving me insane.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One option you might try is to install the language and regions that are missing, then uninstall them.  If that does make them go away, you might want to copy the existing region settings to the "default" profile by going to **Control Panel** >> **Region** >> **Administrative** and clicking the **Copy settings...** button.

If none of this works, you can check out some registry locations and see if the language is listed there.  **Manually changing the registry can severely damage your Windows installation.  Use caution and at your own risk.** The most likely candidate locations are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\KeyboardLayout\Preload
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\KeyboardLayout\Substitutes
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\UserProfile
```

Look for keys within there that have numbers corresponding to [country/region codes in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx).  The US Keyboard should be **409** and the Dutch (Netherlands) one **413**.  If you find and remove any of the 413 references, it may end this problem.

Some other sites in the registry that I found references to the keyboard region are listed below.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-3866501194-3393773080-3339676900-33747\AnyoneRead\LanguageProfile
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-3866501194-3393773080-3339676900-44924\AnyoneRead\LanguageProfile
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile\en-US
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\International\User Profile
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Keyboard Layout\Preload
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3866501194-3393773080-3339676900-33747\Control Panel\International\User Profile
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3866501194-3393773080-3339676900-33747\Keyboard Layout\Preload
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3866501194-3393773080-3339676900-33747\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes
```

If any of these steps fixes it but it all comes back after a reboot, then it's something in your corporate setup (GPO, server script, etc.) that is pushing it back out.  Your only recourse there is probably to contact your IT department and have them fix it.